# Intersection of maximal subgroups isomorphic to $PGL_2(p)$ is of form $PGL_2(p_0)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, projective-space

I want prove (or disprove) that given a finite group G, any two maximal subgroups that are isomorphic to $PGL(2,p)$ where p is prime, then their intersection is isomorphic $PGL(2,q_0)$ (for some $q_0$). I am aware of the fact that intersection of subfields is also a subfield. However, the first statement is unclear to me.

Any comments or suggestion is greatly appreciated !

Comment: Do you seek all such $q_0,$ or maybe such as are integers, primes?

Comment: @coffeemath all such $q_o$ would be good, but I am more interested in prime, if we could find one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many counterexamples.

Take say $G=Sym(4)$. It has four maximal subgroups with are isomorphic to $Sym(3)\cong PGL(2,2)$. Any two of these intersect in a group of order $2$, which is not isomorphic to any $PGL(2,q)$.

If you want an example with $PGL(2,p)$ insoluble, take $G=Alt(7)$. It has a conjugacy class of maximal subgroups isomorphic to $ Sym(5)\cong PGL(2,5)$. The intersection of two such subgroup varies, but can be $A_4$ or dihedral of order $12$, which are not isomorphic to any $PGL(2,q)$.

Comment: I see. Would there also a counter example of G is equal to, say $PSL (2, p^2)$ ?

Comment: Even the smallest case, $p=2$, already yields a counterexample. $PSL(2,4)\cong A_5$ contains maximal subgroups of the form $PGL(2,2)\cong S_3$. Two such subgroups can intersect in a subgroup of order $2$, or even trivially.