# Conditions for intersection of maximal subgroups isomorphic to $PGL(2,p)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, projective-space

Given $G = PSL(2,p^2)$ ($p$ prime), I wish to know what are the possible conditions such that any two maximal subgroups of $G$ that are isomorphic to $PGL(2,p)$, their intersection will contain either a form of $PGL(2,q_1)$ (some $q_1$), $A_5$ or $S_4$ (assuming $q$ is large).

This question is a follow-up question of  [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2365436/intersection-of-maximal-subgroups-isomorphic-to-pgl-2p-is-of-form-pgl-2p-0/2365499#2365499). Therefore, I am aware of the counter examples, thus, wish to know if there are certain constraints that make the desired intersection possible.

Any comments or suggestions are greatly appreciated.